# How to pass index value to controller from ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am dynamically creating divs, while clicking a button which contains some radio inputs. In the controller I have an array for the divs population which initially has a length of 1.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('load').controller(
        'commodityController',

        function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
            $scope.parentload = $scope.$parent.load;

            $scope.addMoreCommodities = function() {
                $scope.parentload.loadCommodities.push({
                    'isHazmat' : false,
                    'dimension' : 'IN'
                });
            }

            $scope.parentload.loadCommodities = []; // emtry array
            $scope.addMoreCommodities();    // Here initialize the array 

            $scope.changeHazmat = function(booleans, val) {
                console.log("booleans " + booleans);
                console.log("isactive " + val);
                $scope.parentload.loadCommodities[val].isHazmat = booleans;
            };  
        });
```

Using following html, while loading the page div populated well,

```
<div class="form-right-card disabledInput" ng-init="showname==true" id="commodityContent">
    <form name="commodityAttForm">
        <div ng-repeat="loadCommodities in load.loadCommodities">
            <div class="form-group33"> {{$index}} // here value prints correctly
                <label class="form-label">Hazmat</label> 
                <input type="radio" class="form-btn-inactive" ng-click="changeHazmat('true',$index)" id="yes" name="hazmat" /> 
                <label class="plsLabel" for="yes">Yes</label> 
                <input type="radio" class="form-btn-inactive" ng-click="changeHazmat('false',$index)" id="no" name="hazmat" />
                <label class="plsLabel" for="no">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<button class="form-btn-link" ng-click="addMoreCommodities()">+ Add Commodity</button>
```

I am able to generate the div with all the inputs when clicking on the button. Problem is, I am sending the `$index` to controller on `ng-click` of the radio buttons, while clicking on the radio buttons, I am calling the function `changeHazmat('true',$index)` **here the index is always 0,** even when I have an array with a length greater than 1.

```
       $scope.changeHazmat = function(selected, val) {
            console.log("val" + val);
            $scope.parentload.loadCommodities[val].isHazmat = selected;
```

Log is always printing the index as 0.

Can someone help me here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check this demo? It's working as you expect right?
 https://plnkr.co/edit/qmS0iU9SAvPyEsm0nyME?p=preview

Comment: This is beside the point, but you might run into problems when you pass the string "true", "false" into changeHazmat rather than the boolean values (without quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly passing the `$index` the controller and the code should work.

However I would recommend to use [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) with [`ngValue`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) directive.

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="loadCommodities.isHazmat" ng-value=true name="hazmat" />
```

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope, ) {
      $scope.parentload = {
        loadCommodities: []
      };

      $scope.addMoreCommodities = function() {
        $scope.parentload.loadCommodities.push({
          'isHazmat': false,
          'dimension': 'IN'
        });
      }
      $scope.addMoreCommodities();

      $scope.changeHazmat = function(booleans, val) {
        $scope.parentload.loadCommodities[val].isHazmat = booleans;
      };
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="loadCommodities in parentload.loadCommodities">
      <div class="form-group33">
        <label class="form-label">Hazmat</label>
        
        <input type="radio" ng-model="loadCommodities.isHazmat" ng-value=true name="hazmat" />
        <label class="plsLabel" for="yes">Yes</label>
        
        <input type="radio" ng-model="loadCommodities.isHazmat" ng-value=false name="hazmat" />
        <label class="plsLabel" for="no">No</label>
      </div>


      <p>{{parentload.loadCommodities}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... I have the following Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/koom2Ffsc6Pa62U1UL9T?p=preview. Able to send the index as expected. But only one radio value is selected for second row as well. I want to select one in each row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the problem is you're assigning the same "id" ('yes' and 'no') to multiple divs (ie inside the loop).  It might be the reason the $index isn't working for you.  If you remove the id's for the time being and re-try, I'm thinking the problem goes away.